# function that returns a dictionary and invoke it only once and assign each property to variables

Tags: python

Goal : Have a function that returns a dictionary with two key values, I want to assign f()['x'] to a variable, and f()['y'] to another, and only call the function once. is it possible?

What I do invoking the function two times,but i would like to invoke it just once:

```
def min_max_price():
    min_max_price_coins = {
        min: {
            "pair": 'btc',

        },
        max: {
            "pair": 'eth',
        }
    }
    # do stuff
    return min_max_price_coins


min_prices = min_max_price()[min]
max_prices = min_max_price()[max]
```

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: You definitely do **not** want dictionary keys that are references to Python built-in functions

Comment: Thank you and the rest for the answres. Why is that Olvin?

Comment: It's because elsewhere in the code, there may be a deliberate override of either *min* or *max* and under those circumstances any lookup attempted on your dictionary will fail. Much better to use unambiguous strings such as 'min' and 'max'. Worth mentioning that if you're using 3.9+ then you can use the @cache decorator (from functools) which would mean that you could call the function twice but the second and subsequent calls would have their responses gleaned from the cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply save returned object first, then assign:

```
obj = min_max_price()
min_prices = obj['min']
max_prices = obj['max']
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a solution?

```py
def min_max_price():
    # ...

minmax = min_max_price()
min_prices = minmax["min"]
max_prices = minmax["max"]
```